Подскажите как сделать модальное окно на wp+woo
Как сделать модальное окно (quick view) для товаров на сайте Wordpress + Woocomemrce. И важно чтобы в модальном окно отображало ссылку на товар в адресной строке, при открытие как тут http://flowry.ru

Не вижу там никакого quick view, вижу модальное окно только при нажатии на "Купить в 1 клик"

Любым устраивающим плагином
